# Create a table from serveral other tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to re-create a XL pivot table in mysql database.

First I retrieve the data from a truck weight scale, import it to a _tb_import_ table in my database.
I also created several other tables with data pertaining the _tb_cost_, _tb_sites_, and several others.
What I want is to INSERT INTO another table (*tb-general*) all the columns of _tb_import_ plus some columns of the other two tables while some will include calculations between _tb_import <> _tb_density_ and _tb_import_ <> _tb_cost_.
Please see this schematics as an example:

**tb_import**

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
+    id     +    date     +  productid  + quant_ton +  site_cd +
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
+     1     +  2016-01-01 +      1      +   20.1    +   1234   +
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
+     2     +  2016-12-01 +      2      +   10.2    +   5678   +
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

**tb_cost**

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
+    id     + productid   +    price    +
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
+     1     +      1      +     2.5     +
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
+     2     +      2      +     1.3     +
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

**tb_sites**

```
+-----------+-----------+----------------------+
+    id     + site_num  +     site_desc        +
+-----------+-----------+----------------------+
+     1     +    1234   + 'work site in here'  +
+-----------+-----------+----------------------+
+     2     +    5678   + 'another work site'  +
+-----------+-----------+----------------------+
```

**tb_product**

```
+-----------+-----------+----------------------+
+    id     +  prod_id  +     product_name     +
+-----------+-----------+----------------------+
+     1     +     1     +      'gravel'        +
+-----------+-----------+----------------------+
+     2     +     2     +       'soil'         +
+-----------+-----------+----------------------+
```

and finally the end result should be:

**tb_general**

```
+-------+-------------+---------+-----------+---------+----+-----+
+  id   +    date     + product + quant_ton + site_cd + X  +  Y  + 
+-------+-------------+---------+-----------+---------+----+-----+
+   1   +  2016-01-01 +'gravel' +   20.1    +  1234   + x1 +  y1 +
+-------+-------------+---------+-----------+---------+----+-----+
+   2   +  2016-12-01 + 'soil'  +   10.2    +  5678   + x2 +  y2 +
+-------+-------------+---------+-----------+---------+----+-----+
```

The **X** column (value) is the product of **quant_ton** with **tb_cost.price**
The **Y** column (site_desc) is the lookup of **import.site_cd** in **tb_site**

Finally I would do a php query to output the table in a php page.

Can I create (INSERT) this new table? If so, how can I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: You certainly can create a new table, but you really shouldn't -- read about the SQL `JOIN` operator.

Comment: Just found 3 table ´JOIN´ in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222097/mysql-left-join-3-tables). As of the calculations in this `JOIN` is it possible?

Comment: Calculations will probably be in the `SELECT` list, not in the `JOIN` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Well after some study I managed to solve it:

```
SELECT date, product_name, quant_ton, site_cd, quant_ton*price as
value, site_desc
FROM tb_import
JOIN tb_cost
ON tb_import.productid = tb_cost.productid
JOIN tb_sites
ON tb_sites.site_num = tb_import.site_cd
JOIN tb_product
ON tb_product.prod_id = tb_import.productid
```

You can see it running in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/056581/2)

Comment: There are some differences between the answer and the question. In the column names: `tb_sites.site_num` vs `tb_sites.id`, similarly for the `cost.product`. And there is no `tb_product` table in the question's DDL. Fix the answer (or the question) so they match.

Comment: You are right just edited it.